# How to solve pygame‑1.9.3‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, pygame, pip

I downloaded `pygame‑1.9.3‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl` from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame. But when I tried to install, it shown error:

[image]

And I checked, `pygame‑1.9.3‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl` should support on my Python platform.

`('cp36', 'cp36m', 'win32')` all matched with the filename. But why I still cannot install it?

I also have my wheel upgraded.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is no longer necessary.  Pygame is a much easier install these days. 
Just do:

```
> pip install pygame
```

and it will automatically select the right download for your environment.